# angular2-multiselect-dropdown shows empty list

Tags: angular, select, dropdown, multi-select

I am using angular2-multiselect-dropdown but the dropdown is empty.

Following is the data in ts file:

```
this.list = [
{
   "docid":1,
   "value": "Europe"
},
{
   "docid":2,
   "value": "ASIA"
},
{
   "docid":3,
   "value": "AFRICA"
},
{
   "docid":4,
   "value": "LATIN AMERICA"
},
{
   "docid":5,
   "value": "NORTH AMERICA"
}

]
```

In HTML :

```
<angular2-multiselect [data]="List" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" 
        (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" 
        (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event)"
        (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
        (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)">
      </angular2-multiselect>
```

In examples, he is using {"id":9,"itemName":"Italy"} which works well. So is there any way that the field itemName can be configured.

https://github.com/CuppaLabs/angular2-multiselect-dropdown
https://cuppalabs.github.io/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/#/basic

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, I found an error in your code.

```
<angular2-multiselect [data]="list" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" 
        (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" 
        (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event)"
        (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
        (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)">
      </angular2-multiselect>
```

Instead of `[data]="List"` you need to write `[data]="list"`.

Then, add a method `map` as say in comment above.

Answer (score 1):

The component is expecting the `[data]` property to be populated in a certain shape. In this case, it should be as follows:

```
export class ListItem{
    id: Number;
    itemName: String
}
```

You will have to transform your list before setting it as the input to data.

You can use map to get this done.

```
this.list = this.list.map((item) => {
  return {
    id: item.docId,
    itemName: item.value
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thought there must be some configuration to resolve this. For now, this looks like a good solution.
It should be item['docId] and item['value']

Answer (score 0):

Add below attribute to angular2-multiselect HTML tag.
[settings]="dropdownSettings"

And configure labelKey as below 
dropdownSettings.labelKey = 'value' instead of itemName which is default;